# JavaFx: Sizing, when a Pane contains text

Tags: java, javafx

In JavaFX, I have a Label (or TextFlow) inside of an AnchorPane (or StackPane), inside of a container Pane.

The container Pane has infinite height, but its width is fixed to be anything I want.

**I need:**

1) The AnchorPane's width to fill all of the available space, but not greater than the label's width when it fits all in one line.

2) The Label to be multiline (wrap=true) and fill all of the available space.

3) The AnchorPane's height to be equal to the height of the Label.

[image]

**The code setup:**

```
Pane rootPane = new Pane();
rootPane.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.FIREBRICK, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));
AnchorPane anchorPane = new AnchorPane();
anchorPane.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.FORESTGREEN, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));
Label text = new Label("text text text text text text text text text text text");
anchorPane.getChildren().add(text);
rootPane.getChildren().add(anchorPane);
```

---

Or, instead of a label I can have:

```
TextFlow text = new TextFlow(new Text("text text text text text text text text text text text"));
```

I've wasted hours on this problem. This is so easy in HTML... How can I achieve this?

Comment: Post a simplified version of your `FXML`.

Comment: @SedrickJefferson I have no FXML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Code

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Background;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundFill;
import javafx.scene.layout.CornerRadii;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Main extends Application { 

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Pane rootPane = new Pane();

        Label text = new Label();        
        text.setWrapText(true);
        text.setText("text text text text text text text text text text text");

        AnchorPane anchorPane = new AnchorPane();
        anchorPane.getChildren().add(text);
        anchorPane.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.FORESTGREEN, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));

        rootPane.getChildren().add(anchorPane);
        rootPane.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.FIREBRICK, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY)));

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(rootPane, 300, 275));
        primaryStage.show();

        rootPane.widthProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {

            private double textWidth;

            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {

                if(text.getWidth() > 0 && textWidth == 0) {
                    textWidth = text.getWidth();
                }

                if(textWidth > 0 && textWidth > rootPane.getWidth())
                {
                    text.setPrefWidth(rootPane.getWidth());
                }else
                {
                    text.setPrefWidth(Label.USE_COMPUTED_SIZE);
                }
            }
        });
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

### Result

[image]

Comment: This doesn't use Labels, but OK, I could use Text. However the problem is that it flickers. To see it, try a longer text. Every other resizing it makes a mistake.

Comment: That’s true. Didn’t see it on my linux machine because my window manager doesn’t update while resizing. It seems like there is some problem with how labels/texts handle wrapping. I’ll have another look at it today and update my answer.

Comment: How do you make these animated gifs from screen capture?

Comment: You need to declare the textWidth field, right?: `private double textWidth;`

Comment: I have added the declaration. Thank you.